# Drawing cards and Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Five cards are dealt from a pack of cards. What is the probability that they form a straight i.e. they are in sequence ? (For example A,2,3,4,5 or 2,3,4,5,6 or say 8,9,10,J,Q. The ace can be low too for example 10,J,Q,K,A is valid; but say J,Q,K,A,2 is not valid). Note that the order of drawing the cards doesn't matter, we can draw the cards in any order and then shuffle to see whether they can be made into  a sequence or not.

My try : To get any valid sequence, say A,2,3,4,5; A have four choices (there are four aces), so does 2 and so on. So any valid string can appear in $4^5$ ways. And from A,2,3,4,5 to 10,J,Q,K,A; there are 10 such possible strings, hence $10\times4^5$ is the no. of favorable ways.

Hence the probability is $10\times 4^5/{52 \choose 5}$.

Am I correct ?

Please help

Comment: Well, if you are talking about poker you have to keep in mind that "straight" excludes "straight flush" and such.  You should specify whether or not you are making that distinction.  Your computation is good if you are not making this exclusion.

Comment: For instance, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) on poker probability excludes straight flushes from "straight" which (I believe) is standard.  Just as two pair excludes four-of-a-kind and full houses.

Comment: @lulu: I don't think there are any other extra conditions ... just as given in the question ...

Comment: There's nothing logically impossible about including things like Royal Flushes as straights...but if you want your answer to tie out to the standard references then you should be aware of the exclusions involved in the definition.